# New user is able to access the photos uploaded by another user

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-storage

These are my Firebase Storage rules.

```
match 
/{allPaths=**} {
     allow read, write: if request.auth != null;
```

This is how users are adding pictures to the storage

```
StorageReference filepathOne = mStorage.child(user_data.getString("uidkey", null)).child("Photos").child("id_one");
```

As you can see I am using the UID as part of the filepath name. My assumption was that, whenever a user uploads the picture they want, only they would be able to access it as they have the unique UID. However, I created a new user account and for some reason, that user is able to access the photos uploaded by another user even though they have different UID.

I should also point out that I am storing the URI in a sharedpref, and then later converting it into a string to have it display the picture.

This is how I store in the SharedPref

```
Uri downloadUrl = taskSnapshot.getDownloadUrl();                        

Picasso.with(getContext())
    .load(downloadUrl)
    .fit().centerCrop()
    .into(image);

editor.putString(user_idone, (taskSnapshot.getDownloadUrl()).toString());                             
editor.commit();
```

This is how I extract from the Pref and display.

```
Picasso.with(getContext())
    .load(Uri.parse(user_data.getString("idonekey", null)))
    .fit().centerCrop()
    .into((ImageView) getView().findViewById(R.id.image));
```

Answer (score 0):

Currently your rules say "anyone can read/write anything, so long as they are authenticated." It sounds like you want to change the rules to mirror your file structure and provide tighter security:

```
service firebase.storage {
  match /b/<your-bucket-name>/o {
    match /{userId}/Photos/{fileName} {
      allow read: if request.auth.uid == userId;
    }
  }
}
```

Our [rules docs](https://firebase.google.com/docs/storage/security/) talk in greater depth on [user and group based security](https://firebase.google.com/docs/storage/security/user-security).